# Create f# class which implements interface using another interface

Tags: generics, types, interface, f#, inference

Let's say I have the following interface **ICreateEnumeratorCollection** which uses another interface **IEnumerable**:

```
open System.Collections

type ICreateEnumeratorCollection =

     abstract member Enumerators : IEnumerable [] with get, set
```

I'm having a tough time creating a class which implements this interface in a generic way:

```
type ExampleClass<'a when 'a :> IEnumerable> (enum : #IEnumerable []) =

     let mutable internalEnum = enum

     interface ICreateEnumeratorCollection with
          member this.Enumerators
              with get ()     = internalEnum
              and set (enum)  = internalEnum <- enum
```

Trying to instantiate this class is a mess as the compiler is not able to implicitly infer the type implementing IEnumerable.

```
let myList = Array.singleton ["bla"]

let listDoesNotMatchIEnumerable = 
    ExampleClass
        (
            myList
        )

let cantInferType = 
    ExampleClass 
        (
            myList 
            |> Array.map (fun x -> x :> IEnumerable)
        )

let worksButIsAlotOfOverhead = 
    ExampleClass<string list>
        (
            myList 
            |> Array.map (fun x -> x :> IEnumerable)
        )
```

Is there a way to define this class in a way which allows the compiler to infer the type using IEnumerable?

Comment: Sry if this example is a bit stupid. In my actual case I have other interfaces arranged in  the same manner. 
Why couldn't an int list work?

Comment: Sorry - deleted my comment, will expand in an answer

Answer (score 1):

Your class signature specifies that the `enum` parameter is of a generic type - i.e. it's not just an array of `IEnumerable`, no. It's an array of some type that implements `IEnumerable`. That's what the hash sign does.

As far as I understand from your further snippets, this is what you actually wanted: you wanted your class to take an array of any list-ish things as parameter.

But here's the problem: if you have an array of `'t` where `'t` implements `IEnumerable`, it's not at all the same as an array of `IEnumerable`.

For illustration:

```
let x : (int list) [] = [||]
let y : IEnumerable [] = x // Compiler error: cannot
```

So when you try to return `enum` from the `Enumerators`, the return type of `Enumerators` must be an array of `IEnumerable`, and since the compiler can't convert array of some unknown `'t` to an array of `IEnumerable`, it assumes that `'t` must itself be `IEnumerable`. Hence the warning you get.

To fix this, assuming you don't want to change the API, you will have to `map` and cast each element down to `IEnumerable`:

```
          with get ()     = internalEnum |> Array.map (fun x -> x :> _)
```

---

But then the next problem you'll see is with `set`, and this one is more serious. Think about it: what if your class works with, say, lists (which do implement `IEnumerable`), but then you try to assign it arrays? Or strings (which are also `IEnumerable`). You can't do that: the type of `internalEnum` doesn't match.

And here's the next question to ask: do you really need your class to be generic? It looks to me like you're not actually using that generic-ness except in the constructor for some syntactic convenience. But syntactic convenience doesn't have to come from a constructor, you can make your class non-generic, and then just have a convenience function for creating it:

```
type ExampleClass (enum : IEnumerable []) =

     let mutable internalEnum = enum

     interface ICreateEnumeratorCollection with
          member this.Enumerators
              with get ()     = internalEnum
              and set (enum)  = internalEnum <- enum

let mkExampleClass (enums: #IEnumerable []) =
    ExampleClass(enums |> Array.map (fun x -> x :> _))
```

Usage:

```
let listDoesNotMatchIEnumerable = 
    mkExampleClass myList
```

Comment: Okay, thank you. Now I understand why this problem arose just when I created this get/set member. But this whole interface inference boggles me a lot. E.g. when looking at your example, one cannot bind the value of x to y, but can instead bind a equivalent value:

let x : (int list) [] = [|[1]|]
let y : IEnumerable [] = x // Compiler error 

let y' : IEnumerable [] = [|[1]|] // works

Answer (score 1):

Your enum parameter is fixed as `IEnumerable []` as that's what required for the interface property.

While you *can* treat e.g. a `string list []` as an `IEnumerable []` (due to the fact arrays are covariant in .NET), it's really not advisable as you'd be able to stick an `int list` in there, which would throw an exception. e.g. imagine this code:

```ml
let list1 : string list [] = Array.singleton ["bla"]
let list2 : IEnumerable [] = list1 |> box |> unbox
list2.[0] <- [1] :> IEnumerable
```

The third line compiles, but throws an `ArrayTypeMismatchException` at runtime because the underlying type is `string list []`.

So, armed with the knowledge above you *can* make your API work as you want - you need can cast the argument to `IEnumerable []`. I'm not sure it's a great idea for the reasons outlined above: the `IEnumerable []` returned by your property can easily throw exceptions when mutated because it's pretending to be something it's not.

```ml
type ExampleClass<'a when 'a :> IEnumerable> (enum:'a []) =

    let mutable internalEnum = enum |> box |> unbox

    interface ICreateEnumeratorCollection with
      member this.Enumerators
          with get ()     = internalEnum
          and set (enum)  = internalEnum <- enum

let result =
    ExampleClass myList
```

Or, a safer, create a new array with the correct type:

```ml
let mutable internalEnum = enum |> Array.map (fun x -> x :> IEnumerable)
```

But as the interface itself isn't generic, I'm not sure the implementation should be. For example, you might create an `ExampleClass<string list>`, but the result is something that has a property of type `IEnumerable []`, which is not generic - you could take the `Enumerators` property from an `ExampleClass<string list>` and set it to the same property on an `ExampleClass<int list>`. While that works, I'm not sure it makes a lot of sense.

It probably more sensible to have a generic factory function that creates an instance of a non-generic type:

```ml
type ExampleClass (enum) =

     interface ICreateEnumeratorCollection with
          member val Enumerators = enum with get, set
          
     static member Create (source:seq<#IEnumerable>) =
         let array = source |> Seq.cast<IEnumerable> |> Array.ofSeq
         ExampleClass array

let result =
    ExampleClass.Create myList
```

The `Create` function just requires a sequence of something that implements `IEnumerable`. It then casts each item and creates an array, which can then be used in your implementation.